# How to get the grapejs editor instance inside model or view of grape's component

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, html-templates, grapesjs

I am using grapejs as a template builder and I want to access grapejs editor instance inside the **model** or **view** of the **component**. When I am passing it as prop to the component while adding it to block manager Error: "**Converting circular structure to JSON**" is thrown by js engine.

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Link to the code which I have tried - https://jsfiddle.net/jamalAshrafi/5kousgpc/9/

Comment: I have found a workaround by making a closure for grapejs instance and then passing it as a property to the editor config object.